# C++: how to convert std::vector operations to Eigen::VectorXf?

Tags: c++, eigen, stdvector

I have this vector operation and I'm trying to implement Eigen:VectorXf to optimise its speed:

```
        for (int m = 0; m < vectorSize; ++m)
        {
            A[m] = ((B[m] * C[m]) + ((D[m] * E[m]) + (F[m] * G[m])));

            H[m] = A[m] * I[m];

            out = out + H[m];

            E[m] = C[m];
            C[m] = A[m];
        }
```

'out' is a float variable. What would be the best way to implement this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Remove the loop, and all the `[m]`s? [`out = H.sum()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#addd7080d5c202795820e361768d0140c)

Comment: I did that but crashes when I run it

Comment: Did you make sure all your vectors have the same length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vectors you have to use `array()` to get component-wise multiplication. You can use the `sum()` function to compute `out` as the sum of elements of H.

```
VectorXf  B, C, D, E, F, G, I;
//...
// Assuming all vectors have the same size

const VectorXf A = ((B.array() * C.array()) + (D.array()) * E.array()) + (F.array() * G.array());
const VectorXf H = A.array() * I.array();
const float out = H.sum();

E = C;
C = A;
```

Note that if your vector size is known at compile time it might be better to use `Matrix<float,vectorSize,1>` instead of `VectorXf`

Comment: Thanks @Louen . This definitely helped. My program is crashing if I try to add the last bracket (F * G). I know all vectors are the same size. Is there something I need to check after the first addition? Or after multiplying F and G? Is there anything I might have in there that is changing the vector size?  Sadly the the vector sizes are not known at compile time so I need to keep the VectorXf.

Comment: What do you mean by crashing ? Do you get an error message ? Did you use a debugger ?